# Why MVC model binding correctly resolve complex object if request is issued by POST and dosen't resolve if issued by GET?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my controller i defined a Customer viewmodel class like below.

There are two properties FirstName, LastName and a 3rd property Orders wich is a collection of Order

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }
}

public class TestController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult TestCustomer1(Customer customer)
    {
        return Json(customer);
    }
}
```

I submit data to the controller by an ajax call when client click a button and invoke `OnCustomerClick()`

```
function OnCustomerClick() {

    var complexObject = {
        FirstName: 'Saroj',
        LastName: 'K',
        Orders: [{ OrderId: 1, OrderBy: 'Saroj' }, { OrderId: 2, OrderBy: 'Kumar' }]
    };

    var obj = { customer: complexObject };
    var data2send = obj;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'TestCustomer1',
        data: data2send,
        success: function (arg) { //call successfull
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //error occurred
        }
    });
};
```

The point is when the action is invoked like above by a **type: POST** request the Customer parameter in the controller action is successfully populated, when instead i invoke the action by a **type: GET** the parameter object is instantiated with properties set to null.

The string that represents the serialized object is exactly the same in both of the two cases, only change the way that string is passed to the action: body request in the first case, url parameter in the second one.

**Request body in POST request**
customer%5BFirstName%5D=Saroj&customer%5BLastName%5D=K&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5BOrderId%5D=1&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5BOrderBy%5D=Saroj&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5BOrderId%5D=2&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5BOrderBy%5D=Kumar

**Query string in GET request**
/TestCustomer1?customer%5BFirstName%5D=Saroj&customer%5BLastName%5D=K&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5BOrderId%5D=1&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5BOrderBy%5D=Saroj&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5BOrderId%5D=2&customer%5BOrders%5D%5B1%5D%5BOrderBy%5D=Kumar

Can anyone enlighten me on this to why the behavior of model binding change in the two cases?

Comment: For a GET, it needs to be `var complexObject = {  FirstName: 'Saroj', LastName: 'K', Orders[0].OrderId: 1, Orders[0].OrderBy: 'Saroj', Orders[1].OrderId: 2, Orders[1].OrderBy: 'Kumar' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between GET and POST requests is that a POST body can have a content type so they can be interpreted correctly on the server side as XML, or Json, so on; for GET, all you have is just a query string.
So if you put your complex type as query string in your url it works correctly.
for example for an array in a query string could be like this:
http://SomeHost/GetArray?TestData[0].a=1&Data[0].b=1&Data[1].a=2&Data[1].b=2&Data[2].a=3&Data[2].b=3

Comment: No is not that the point. I just want to know why the same object is resolved by model binding  when is submitted with a Post and is not resolved  when the same object is serialized as querystring parameter in a Get call. The string that rappresent the serialized object is the same in both of the two cases.

Comment: If you change your url according to your complex type it must work correctly, as you said i changed my answer ...

Comment: I can't agree with you. Exactly the same string  is posted in the request when POST or  attached  to the  query-string  when GET but the behavior of the model binding is not the same

Comment: What is your exact query string?